# How to lock and unlock a table exclusively outside of a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, how can a table be locked and unlocked (exclusively) **outside of a transaction**?

Reason: multiple instances of my app need to interact with one table without stepping on each other's toes, while at the same time executing a statement that cannot run within a transaction

Comment: In what context. Far too vague

Comment: Locks are generally held only for the duration of a transaction. Perhaps what you want is a session level application lock.

Comment: Application lock could possibly do the job. I'll happily accept an answer that solves it that way.

Comment: Looks like you needs to keep access blocked for one table except when your app is interacting with it. Maybe you can look in users permissions, Example give permission to only your app to use insert in a table and let other users to only select it by using a view.

Comment: No I need multiple instances of my app to interact with one table without stepping on each other's toes, while at the same time executing a statement that cannot run within a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to look into [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) and [sp_releaseapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql).

This would not lock the table, but an arbitrary named resource. You could then configure your application to only work with the table in question after the lock has been acquired, e.g., through stored procedures.

An example of this would be something like:

```
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'ResourceName', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockOwner = 'Session'

-- UPDATE table, etc.

EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'ResourceName', @LockOwner = 'Session'
```

Specifying `@LockOwner = 'Session'` means you can use this locking mechanism outside of a transaction.

There's also the option of extracting the locking and releasing statements into their own stored procedures, so the logic is only stated once; these stored procedures could return a value to the calling procedure with a result specifying whether or not the lock has been acquired/released.

At that point it's just a question of ensuring that this mechanism is put into place for every procedure/table/etc. where there may be contention.